# What is meaning of -(Class)class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my sample code:

```
View *v1 = [View new];
NSLog(@"%d",([v1 isKindOfClass:[View class]]));
NSLog(@"%d",([[v1 class] isKindOfClass:[View class]]));
```

`View` is a class, now I have some confusion:

1. v1 is an instance of View, and View is an instance of View's meta class, right?
2. return value of `[v1 class]` is an pointer named `isa` point to class object, right?
3. return value of `[View class]` is an pointer named `isa` point to meta class, right?
4. I log address of `[v1 class]` and `[View class]`, they are equal, why?

   ```
   NSLog(@"%p", [v1 class]);
   NSLog(@"%p", [View class]);

   2018-01-05 10:47:30.554190+0800 Block[16532:785147] 0x10a61a178
   2018-01-05 10:47:30.554300+0800 Block[16532:785147] 0x10a61a178
   ```
5. I guess the key point is the return value of `[View class]`, so if the return value of `[View class]` does not point to its meta class, who is it ?? who is it point to ??

**Edit**

I got some informations from apple document, [type method of -class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1571950-class) and [instance method of class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571949-class), the two method have same return value, named `class object`, what's this ? the instance of meta class ?? and how to get metaclass ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. v1 is an instance of View, and View is an instance of View's meta class, right?

`v1` is an instance of `View`.

You cannot use `View` as a regular C identifier, only as the recipient of class messages (like `[View new]`), but there is a real object that receives those class messages. It's common and convenient to call that the `View` class object, and it is the only instance of the `View` metaclass.

> 2. return value of `[v1 class]` is an pointer named `isa` point to class object, right?

`[v1 class]` returns a reference to the `View` class object. The `isa` “pointer” is an implementation detail and in fact its implementation has changed. See [“Non-pointer isa”](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2013/09/24/objc_explain_Non-pointer_isa.html).

> 3. return value of `[View class]` is an pointer named `isa` point to meta class, right?

`[View class]` means exactly the same thing as `[View self]`.  Both return the `View` class object, not a metaclass object. You can see this in [the Objective-C runtime source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-723/runtime/NSObject.mm.auto.html). I will quote the relevant method definitions here.

```
+ (id)self {
    return (id)self;
}
```

When you say `[View self]`, it runs the `+[NSObject self]` method quoted above, with the local variable `self` pointing to the `View` class object. (Whew, that's a lot of “self”!) So `[View self]` returns the `View` class object:

```
- (id)self {
    return self;
}
```

When you say `[v1 self]`, it runs the `-[NSObject self]` method quoted above, with the local variable `self` pointing to the `v1` object (a `View` instance). So `[v1 self]` returns `v1`.

```
+ (Class)class {
    return self;
}
```

When you say `[View class]`, it runs the `+[NSObject class]` method quoted above, with the local variable `self` pointing to the `View` class object. So `[View class]` returns the `View` class object, just like `[View self]` does.

```
- (Class)class {
    return object_getClass(self);
}
```

When you say `[v1 class]`, it runs the `-[NSObject class]` method quoted above, with the local variable `self` pointing to the `v1` object (a `View` instance). This method has a different body than the three other methods above. This method uses the Objective-C runtime function `object_getClass` to get a reference to the `View` class object.

> 4. I log address of [v1 class] and [View class], they are equal, why?
>
>    ```
>    NSLog(@"%p", [v1 class]);
>    NSLog(@"%p", [View class]);
>
>    2018-01-05 10:47:30.554190+0800 Block[16532:785147] 0x10a61a178
>    2018-01-05 10:47:30.554300+0800 Block[16532:785147] 0x10a61a178
>    ```

As I explained above, both of these return the `View` class object.

> 5. I guess the key point is the return value of [View class], so if the return value of [View class] does not point to its meta class, who is it ?? who is it point to ??

`[View class]` returns the same thing as `[View self]`: the `View` class object. If you want to get a reference to the `View` metaclass object, you need to use the Objective-C runtime directly, like this:

```
NSLog(@"%p", object_getClass([View class]));
```

Note that if you print `[View class]` with `%@`, it just prints `View`. And if you print `object_getClass([View class])` with `%@`, it also just prints `View`. You cannot distinguish between the `View` class object and the `View` metaclass object by their string descriptions. You have to look at the pointer values (which is indeed what you were doing).

Here is my test:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface View: NSObject
@end

@implementation View
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        View *v1 = [View new];
        NSLog(@"v1 = %@ / %p", v1, v1);
        NSLog(@"[v1 class] = %@ / %p", [v1 class], [v1 class]);
        NSLog(@"[[v1 class] class] = %@ / %p", [[v1 class] class], [[v1 class] class]);
        NSLog(@"[View class] = %@ / %p", [View class], [View class]);
        NSLog(@"object_getClass([View class]) = %@ / %p", object_getClass([View class]), object_getClass([View class]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output (with `NSLog` fluff removed):

```
v1 = <View: 0x101600780> / 0x101600780
[v1 class] = View / 0x1000011e0
[[v1 class] class] = View / 0x1000011e0
[View class] = View / 0x1000011e0
object_getClass([View class]) = View / 0x1000011b8
```

So:

- my `v1` object is at 0x101600780,
- the `View` class object is at 0x1000011e0,
- and the `View` metaclass object is at 0x1000011b8.

You might wonder **why** `[View class]` returns the `View` class object instead of the `View` metaclass object. Greg Parker is the main Apple employee who maintains the Objective-C runtime, and he explains why in [a blog post titled “Classes and metaclasses”](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html):

> Objective-C uses metaclasses for practical goals like class methods, but otherwise tends to hide metaclasses. For example, `[NSObject class]` is identical to `[NSObject self]`, even though in formal terms it ought to return the metaclass that `NSObject->isa` points to. The Objective-C language is a set of practical compromises; here it limits the class schema before it gets too, well, *meta*.

Comment: I think you are right, thank you, now, I am going to visit the blog!! Thx!!